# Phonegap android quickstart problem

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am following [this](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/30862722/phonegap-android-eclipse-quickstart) guide to getting phonegap set-up. As soon as I try to build the sample in eclipse the console throws the following errors:

```
[2011-07-29 13:19:36 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read D:\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
[2011-07-29 13:19:36 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read D:\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I am using the 2.3.3 api version, phonegap 0.9.6 and windows 7.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

This alternative wiki link is an easier way to get started with PhoneGap, Android and Eclipse - [PhoneGap Eclipse PlugIn](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap-Eclipse-PlugIn-for-Android)

Comment: Doesn't help. I'm going to use Phonegap Build.

Comment: This link has nothing to do with PhoneGap Build.  It describes how to get and use an Eclipse plugin that makes Android PhoneGap development easier. The plugin adds JavaScript and PhoneGap extensions to the standard Android Development Tools (ADT)

Comment: I meant that I'm going to use PhoneGap Build instead of the Eclipse method.